# Ubuntu 16.04: How to update YubiKey Personalization Tool (GUI) with latest library?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, libraries, yubikey

I have a new Yubikey 4 with firmware v4.3.5.

I've downloaded YubiKey Personalization Tool v3.1.24 ([here](https://www.yubico.com/support/knowledge-base/categories/articles/yubikey-personalization-tools/)), moved it to my offline machine and compiled it after I've installed all needed .deb-files (dependecies).

Starting the YubiKey Personalization Tool GUI shows me, that it has the Library version 1.17.2. The [compatibilty site](https://developers.yubico.com/yubikey-personalization/Compatibility.html) shows me that I need minimum the Library version 1.17.3. Latest Library available is 1.18.0. The GUI shows me also that the firmware of my YubiKey (4.3.5) is unkown.

Now I am asking you: How can I update the library of the YubiKey Personalization Tool GUI?

Important: If I have to download anything, I have to do it on my online-machine and move the files to my offline-machine. So, things like `git clone` or anything else don't work for me.

If it doesn't work I guess I have to use the YubiKey Personalization Tool from the command line but I really don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. Here's the answer:

https://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=2746

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.